# Can a single counter question provide a valid answer on SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I have come over this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25474673/1413395)

> *"Is dataManager.cpp included in your build?"*

and had a little dispute with the author, if it can be considered as a valid answer at all, since there's only a single counter question statement.

Though in this case a counter question statement could initiate getting the OP enlightened with the actual answer, I doubt it can be considered as a valid answer on SO standing in itself.

I have downvoted the answer, and flagged for deletion (I don't care if it was accepted by the OP). What do you think?

Comment: Who the hell is voting to close this as "cannot be reproduced"? Wut?

Comment: @bjb568 Not that the "cannot be reproduced" reason also includes "simple typographical error." I'd say most people were actually using it for the latter reason.

Comment: I think this trend of flagging and voting to delete helpful answers just because they contain a question mark is really troubling.  If you want to edit the answer to make it more definitive, go ahead. But there's no reason to delete it.

Comment: @AShelly In which way would you say the answer cited above is helpful for anyone else than the OP actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The OP probably isn't the only person ever (and won't be the last person ever) to have forgotten to include a file in their build.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland And most probably another OP will need not to forget **something else** then `dataManager.cpp` to include in their build.

Comment: I have no clue why this question was closed as ***not reproducible***. There isn't anything to reproduce. The linked Q&A was deleted, and the answer in question was finally edited (check the edit history for the 1st version (+10k rep users can do so here)). I've accepted that editing the answer (instead of requesting deletion) would be the right action IMHO (shared with currently 35 upvoters).

Comment: @Angew What's the _simple typographical error_ (or meta equivalent) in my question, that would fit for closing my question? That the simple answer is _"No, a question is not an answer."_ from the general semantical POV, or what do you mean? Enlighten me please :-/ ...

Comment: @Angew bjb was referring to who was voting to close *this question*  on meta as "cannot be reproduced". Though it's now closed... and will hopefully soon be reopened.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I misunderstood - I thought it was about the main-site question, not about this meta one. This one of course shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If an SO user can't extrapolate 'OP was using dataManager.cpp and forgot to include it, I'm using otherFile.cpp perhaps I've forgotten to include it.' from the above answer then perhaps programming isn't the career/hobby for them!

For clarity I don't think question answers as above are acceptable, if it had a paragraph after along the lines of 'You need to make sure you include all the files your project is using.' it would be ok, if it explained how to do that it would be even better.

However your questions was 'How is the answer above helpful?' and my reply explains that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Can a single counter question provide a valid answer on SO?

No it can't. It's not the form an answer should have. Answers should be stated in a definitive manner. Not a "Could you try.." or "Have you made sure that ...".

That said, in this particular case we don't really need all this debate, do we? It's clear what the OP of the answer is trying to say. The OP of the question indicated that it indeed was the cause of the problem, so use the tools available to you and edit the answer into shape. Job done.

Comment: That said, new users can not comment, but just answer. They need a certain reputation to be allowed to comment. This keeps new authors from asking for more details (and may lead to this kind of just-a-question pseudo-answers).

Comment: Sure @Alex. At which point such answers are subject to deletion.

Comment: Yeah let's drive away new users from stack overflow.

Comment: If the counter question is intended to be an answer, then word it as a definitive statement. (E.g., "make sure datamanager.cpp is included in your build.") If it is only meant to ask a question of the OP, then enter it as a comment. Of course, as was mentioned, new users can't leave comments, so in that case, leave an answer, and include a polite request for a mod to convert it to a comment.

Answer (score 10):

No.

That's not a valid answer; it doesn't matter that the OP accepted it or even that it eventually *lead* to the answer.

Answers should provide a complete, documented, and well-explained response to the question. Countering a question with a single other question does not fulfill those conditions.

In other cases, the line becomes blurrier: say, if the answer is a series of questions with takeaways from each that lead more explicitly to an answer or if it provides a reason for the OP to ask him/herself that question.

However, in this case (and any others where the question is only asking for clarification), refer to the comment tooltip:

> Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. [...]

In essence, that's exactly what that "answer" was doing, and it was the wrong place. If you want to counter a question with an answer, make sure you elaborate on why that question is necessary and *how it leads to an answer*.

Answer (score 3):

This particular question deserved to be closed because it was not helpful to anyone other than the OP.

But in general, a helpful answer that contains a question mark should not be downvoted, deleted or flagged just because of the wording.

Yes, SO is designed to be a Question and Answer site.  As the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) says:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

But the ugly truth is that many good questions here don't start with quite enough information to give a definitive answer.  Ideally, given a question with most but not all of the information needed to solve it, the next step would be a comment asking for clarification.

But that doesn't always happen.  What does happen often are speculative answers ranging in style:

"Did you try Y?"
"Is it situation X?  Y should solve it".
"This might be situation X, try Y"
"That information is consistent with situation X, which needs Y to solve it"

We do have discussion here - we have to - it's part of problem solving.   And when answers of this type are accepted, then primary mission accomplished.  Question asked, Answer received.  Even if the form leaves something to be desired.

It's great to attempt to make the whole question more useful to others by rewording the first example into the last.  Definitely do that.

But it's just wrong to flag that type of answer for deletion.  You don't further the site's mission to  "Build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"  by destroying the building blocks.

Comment: _"that contains a question mark"_ That wasn't in question. I had clearly stated that I just meant a single counter question without any more explanatory text in the answer. I doubt it's likely that this form will ever make a good answer. For discussion we have comments, not answers.

Comment: Its a trend I'm seeing and I don't like. This is the first meta question about it I've seen and I wanted to highlight it.